# Can the spell Freedom of Movement allow a character to escape a Forcecage spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, eldritch-invocations

If a Warlock with the Trickster's Escape (Eldritch Invocation XGtE) uses his power to cast [Freedom of Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/freedom-of-movement), would that allow him to escape a [Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, *Freedom of Movement* does not counteract a *Forcecage*

*Freedom of Movement* has five principle effects:

- Target is unaffected by Difficult Terrain
- Target cannot have their speed reduced [by magical effects]
- Target cannot be Paralyzed or Restrained [by magical effects]
- Target can automagically escape from non-magical bindings using 5' of movement
- Target does not get disadvantage from underwater combat

None of these effects are consequences of the effects of *Forcecage*, which only creates a [magical] barrier that the creature cannot pass through. As a result, *Freedom of Movement* has no effect on a creature trapped by a *Forcecage*.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

*Freedom of Movement* doesn't give a creature carte blanche to move wherever it wants (e.g. through walls), it just prevents some specific effects (in addition to allowing escape from grapples and non-magical restraints for a cost of 5ft of movement):

- extra movement costs from difficult terrain
- reduction of speed caused by spells or magical effects
- the paralyzed condition caused by spells or magical effects
- the restrained condition caused by spells or magical effects
- penalties to movement or attack due to being underwater

A *Forcecage* does not reduce the speed of creatures inside it, and creatures inside of it are neither paralyzed nor restrained. Essentially, it's just a collection of six walls of force which happen to be arranged in such a way that it's really inconvenient for anyone in a 10- or 20-foot cube.